# Getting jquery.texteffects.js to work with dream function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying for hours to get the texteffects.js to work with the Dream function below.
I have tried surrounding the text with a div, I have also, instead of doing document.ready, created a function and called it from the Dream Document.Ready event.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script>
<title></title>
<style>
 body{
  background:black;
  overflow:hidden;
  color:white;
  font-size:2em;
 }
 .drawingpix { 
position:absolute; 
top:-50px; 
left:-50px;
}

 </style>

 </head>

 <body>
 <p id="typetext">
    The text to display
 </p>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery.texteffects.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //the function that creates dream
    function dream() {
        //calculating random color of dream
        var color = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ',' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ')';

        //calculating random X position
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width());

        //calculating random Y position
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height());

        //creating the dream and hide
        drawingpix = $('<span>').attr({ class: 'drawingpix' }).hide();

        //appending it to body
        $(document.body).append(drawingpix);

        //styling dream.. filling colors.. positioning.. showing.. growing..fading
        drawingpix.css({
            'background-color': color,
            'border-radius': '100px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '100px',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '100px',
            top: y - 14,    //offsets
            left: x - 14 //offsets
        }).show().animate({
            height: '500px',
            width: '500px',
            'border-radius': '500px',
            '-moz-border-radius': '500px',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '500px',
            opacity: 0.1,
            top: y - 250,    //offsets
            left: x - 250
        }, 3000).fadeOut(2000);

         //Every dream's end starts a new dream
         window.setTimeout('dream()', 200);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //calling the first dream
        dream();

    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#typetext p").texteffects({ "texteffect": "unexplode", "speed": "slow", "delay": "1000" });
    });
 </script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the jQuery.texteffects.js was in my project, it was not an include.
Once I included it, it worked.

Thanks